# Call xml for ajax does not print

Tags: jquery, xml

I am trying to print the value of a given xml, what's wrong?

HTML

```
<div class="well">
     <h2 class="title">Parse XML</h2>
    <hr>
    <div id="output"></div>
</div>
```

[javascript and fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6wQsR/9/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6wQsR/9/

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the ajax success call to the following:

```
function parseXml(xml) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(xml));
    // $(xml).find("guitar").each(function () {
    //     var name = $(this).find("make").text();
    //     var url = $(this).find("model").text();
    //     $("#output").append(name + "<br />" + url + "<br /><br /><br />");
    // });
}

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "yourUrl", // set the path to your file
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (data) {
        parseXml(data);
    }, // call the function parseXml
    error: function (data) {
        data["error"] = "We hit an error!";
        parseXml(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: continues without printing. may be missing some kind of permission to the xml?

Comment: It keeps on hitting error in the ajax call, oddly enough the data comes through as I can see it in fiddler ...

Comment: generated a big mistake on alert.